# How to deserialize a test a List<Oject> with jackson / junit4 / spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, jackson

I have two questions in one :

First of all, I'm trying to test a post-petition with Junit4, I have something like this :

```
  @Test
public void postTest()
{
  final String contentToSave = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/test/resources/savePost.json")));

  final ObjectNode jsonContentToSave = (ObjectNode) objectMapper.readTree(contentToSave);

  mockMvc.perform(post(apiContext
      + "/url/default/").session(httpSession).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                                                        .content(jsonContentToSave.toString()))
}
```

This code, that works to me in other petition, throw me an exception if I use this type of JSON

```
[
  {
    "color": "white",
    "jobs": {
        "name": "default",
        "time": 40
    },
    "number": 4
  }
]
```

The error :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode cannot be cast to class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode and com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

And the other problem that I have with Jackson , is deserialize this json , I try something like this , but not found at all :

```
public static List<ObjectClass> jsonToObject(final JsonNode jsonData){
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   List<ObjectClass> myObjects = null;
  try{
    myObjects = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData.textValue(),
                                     new TypeReference<List<ObjectClass>>() {
                                     });
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
return myObjects;
}
```

I'm nooby in Jackson, therefore, all advice is welcome, thx !!

Comment: Hi, I don't have much time to explain it today but I've created an example solving your issue, you can find it here https://github.com/marcosbarbero/spring-boot-mockmvc-file-to-jackson-example

Comment: Hi @MarcosBarbero, I read your code and I have some questions about that. What happened if I need to get a List<Person>, with only change (@RequestBody Person person) to (@RequestBody List<Person> person) is enough? And thx for answering me!

Comment: Unfortunately I’m away from my computer for the next days, you can just change the RequestBody to expect a list of person and send an array of it while performing your request

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify `postTest` test method by removing second line:

```
final ObjectNode jsonContentToSave = (ObjectNode) objectMapper.readTree(contentToSave);
```

Just provide `contentToSave` to `content` method: `.content(contentToSave)`.

But, if you really want to do that, just replace `ObjectNode` with `ArrayNode`. `ArrayNode` will be used when top level element is a `JSON Array` e.g. `[1,2,3]`. Both `ArrayNode` and `ObjectNode` extends [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) and you can use it safely.

`jsonToObject` method accepts `JsonNode` and you do not need to serialise it to `String` and deserialise back to another type. You can use [convert](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue-java.lang.Object-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference-) method:

```
objectMapper.convert(jsonData, new TypeReference<List<ObjectClass>>() {});
```

Comment: Hi , this implementation throw me the following error : `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not construct instance of gcs.fds.api.history.ActionInfo: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])` Do you have idea ?

Comment: @Laa-Laa, it looks like `ActionInfo` class and its constructor does not match to `JSON Object` you want to deserialise. It looks like it is a new question and new problem - you can accept this answer if it was helpful and create new question with all details: `ActionInfo` class and `JSON` payload you want to deserialise.